# json.loads converts valid JSON to invalid JSON

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using django-rest-framework to validate some JSON received in my webhook and then I save some of the fields to my database. That mostly works now.

The JSON comes from a third party and varies in format and isn't well documented. My view is therefore grabbing the complete JSON using json.loads and saving it in a separate table so that I have it to help me troubleshoot any requests that fail validation.

However I'm finding that the JSON that gets returned by json.loads is slightly different to the JSON that the third party claims to be sending. The third party is sending strings and values in double-quotes but json.loads returns the same in single quotes. The third party is sending false and true values in lowercase but json.loads returns them capitalised, ie True and False. Thus making the JSON invalid.

The serialisers are validating the JSON received in the webhook as valid. But if I take the same JSON post returned by json.loads and post it again using Postman then the serializers reject it as invalid.

Is it normal for json.loads to return JSON formatted in this way with the invalid single quotes and capitalised True/False values?

```
transaction_json_data = json.loads(request.body)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON library in python converts JSON string into a python understandable, list and dictionary. That is the reason the 'true' and 'false' strings were converted into python Boolean True and False. Usually, you don't store JSON objects but JSON strings in NoSQL databases. 
Here is the official documentation, for more information
https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html